# Implementing thread pool for stored procedure calls

Tags: c#, sql-server, multithreading, stored-procedures

First, let me start with saying that I am a C# beginner.  My background has mostly been with databases.  I am working on a project where there will be frequent calls to a C# server which then calls various stored procedures (about 20 or so) to retrieve data from a SQL Server DB.  Right now, the C# server was set up doing synchronous calls.  While the SP calls are quick and small, we would still like to implement a thread pool to handle a large pool of users and simultaneous requests.

My questions:

1. How do I implement a thread pool?  Most likely, the thread pool will start around 500, but could grow depending on use of the application.
2. How do I add the SP calls to the thread pool.  Right now my SP call looks like this:

   ```
   int SPCall(string param1, string param2)
   {
     string MyConnString = "...";
     SqlConnection MyConn = new SqlConnection(MyConnString);
     MyConn.Open();
     SqlCommand SPCommand = new SqlCommand("wh_SP");
     SPCommand.Connection = MyConn;
     SPCommand.Parameters.Add(...) = param1;  
     SPCommand.Parameters.Add(...) = param2;  

     SPCommand.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure;
     SPCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
     int outPut = (int)SPCommand.Parameters["@OUTPUT"].Value;
     return outPut;
    }
   ```

Comment: Don't roll your own thread pool - use the [built-in](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.threadpool.aspx) one. There's documentation there on how to queue work items.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the comments, you should use the .NET ThreadPool instead of implementing your own.  Even better, use the newer [.NET Parallel library](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd460717.aspx) and chunk each of these out into a task.  You will have far better control over how your concurrency is handled with relatively little code.

```
public void PerformWork()
{
    // setup your inputs
    IEnumerable<string> inputs = CreateYourInputList();

    //  Method signature: Parallel.ForEach(IEnumerable<TSource> source, Action<TSource> body)
    Parallel.ForEach(inputs, input =>
        {
            // call your code that issues the stored procedure here
            this.SPCall(input);
        } //close lambda expression
    ); //close method invocation 

    // Keep the console window open in debug mode.
    Console.WriteLine("Processing complete. Press any key to exit.");
    Console.ReadKey();
}
```